# How do I link a C++/CLI library to C++ application

Tags: c++, cmake, c++-cli

I made a C++/CLI wrapper for using a C# DLL in a C++ application. I used Visual Studio to manage the projects and manage the dependencies, and I got it to work that way.

But I can't get it to work when I use CMake to link the library that Visual Studio built for me.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

project(playground CXX)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(PLAYGROUND_SOURCE_DIR ${CCMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(PLAYGROUND_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

set(PLAYGROUND_SRC
main.cpp)

add_executable(Playground ${PLAYGROUND_SRC} ${PLAYGROUND_HDR})

find_library(comm_dll CommWrapper Lib/CommDLL)

target_link_libraries(Playground PUBLIC
${comm_dll}
)
```

Using this method gets me an "unresolved external symbol error". I have the .dll, .lib and .h file in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant already stated: you must compile your C++/CLI code as Dynamic Library in order to be able to consume it from an unmanaged application. CLI/Managed code cannot run from/cannot reside in static libraries. If you change the C++/CLI library target from Static library to Dynamic library you'll be able to compile successfully your unmanaged C++ application.

One thought from my side: I think you'll be better if you use mixed mode C++/CLI DLLs to consume the managed functionality - you'll be able to free your consumer application completely from referencing the CLR.

The Header of such mixed mode Wrapper for your Element class would look like this:

```
#pragma once

#pragma unmanaged

#if defined(LIB_EXPORT)
#define DECLSPEC_CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC_CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class ElementWrapperPrivate;

class __declspec(dllexport) ElementWrapper
{
private:
    ElementWrapperPrivate* helper;

public:
    ElementWrapper();
    ~ElementWrapper();
public:
    void ExecuteCommand();
};
```

And the implementation would look like this:

```
#include "ElementWrapper.h"
#pragma managed

#include "Element.h"
#include <msclr\auto_gcroot.h>

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

class ElementWrapperPrivate
{
public:
    msclr::auto_gcroot<Element^> elementInst;  // For Managed-to-Unmanaged marshalling
};

ElementWrapper::ElementWrapper()
{
    helper = new ElementWrapperPrivate();
    helper->elementInst = gcnew Element();
}

ElementWrapper::~ElementWrapper()
{
    delete helper;
}

void ElementWrapper::ExecuteCommand()
{
    helper->elementInst->ExecuteCommand();
}
```

Then just compile your Element.cpp + ElementWrapper.cpp to a DLL and use the ElementWrapper.h in your unmanaged applications.

Comment: I already did this. I got the wrapper to work in an unmanaged C++ application, but Visual Studio helped with the dependencies. My question is how to get this to work with CMake.